# How to suppress displaying pending (skipped) specs in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have several skipped specs.

```
Pending: (Failures listed here are expected and do not affect your suite's status)

1) ...
   # Not yet implemented
   # ./spec/requests/request_spec.rb:22
```

How to suppress the output of pending specs?

Comment: Surprisingly, `rspec --tag ~skip` worked.

Comment: The question this is marked as a duplicate of does not actually have any answers that suppress the "pending tests" section described in this question. (And, for that matter, neither does `--tag ~skip`, as far as I can tell.)

Answer (score 3):

You can add the following config option to filter out all pending specs from the run:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.filter_run_excluding skip: true
end
```

Also, [here](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/2377#issuecomment-275131981) is a more elaborate suggestion to suppress the output

Answer (score -4):

You can do it by replacing "it" in the test header with "xit".

```
it "returns true" do
    1.should == 1
end
```

Replace with:

```
xit "returns true" do
    1.should == 1
end
```

Adding x before it will skip this test.

Comment: RSpec skips the spec but reports it as a pending spec.